# registering to receive GCM for Android, where to and how many times?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have been reading the docs about gcm and I understand I have to register to receive GCM messages on the `onCreate` method of my main `Activity`. However, what if I have different entry points for my app. Where do I have to set the code that registers the app to the GCM? Do I have to write `GCMRegistrar.register(this, Constants.GCM_PROJECT_ID)` in every `onCreate` method of every `Activity` that acts as an entry point? Is there any other way?

One entry point is the main `Activity`, however the user can also jump to a detail screen from a Notification.

Thanks!

Comment: Write it in onCreate of Application class only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an Application Class for your App, and there you will can register for GCM on App startup without taking care of the Activity that is receiving the corresponding Intent.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Check onCreate method

Comment: Ok, I actually thought about this as the best way of doing it. However the Aplication Class is not called everytime the app is opened because it is a singleton and remains in memory. Therefore the token can expire and it will not be refreshed until the app is totally stoped and started again.. am I right?

Comment: Ok, I was wrong, now I understand it. I don't need to register everytime I open the app because if the Registration ID expires, Google sends the new one automatically to my IntentService.

Comment: Exactly, you only have to receive the expired id broadcast, to renew it